# syntax of isBlank() function

Tags: openrefine

value.isBlank() gives me the following error: "Parsing error at offset 14: Unknown function isBlank"
It sounds weird, because isBlank(value) is working well, and both syntax value.function() and function(value) are supported by GREL.
Is it a bug?
M. Saby

Comment: I can just confirm that none of [these tests](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Controls#isblank-isnonblank-isnull-isnotnull-isnumeric-iserror) work in the form value.functionName(). Feel free to open an issue on Github if that's a problem for you.

Comment: you can report an issue from this page: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/new

Comment: For the information of all, the explanation is that isBlank() and co looks like functions but they are not, they are controls.